# Jax-ws not supported by IBM WebSphere 8.5 Liberty Profile

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, websphere-liberty

While trying to deploy a JAX-WS application in WebSphere 8.5 Liberty profile is throwing "JAXWS" not supported error. Tried to configure the feature manager but cant find JAX-WS plugin in it.

Comment: Add feature jaxws-2.2 to the features in your server.xml file...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version you downloaded? Please download the latest one from [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/) . For jax-ws you need to download and install also extended part - `wlp-extended-8.5.5.5.jar`.

To verify that you have jax-ws-2.2 feature run the following command:

```
C:\WebSphere\wlp\bin>productInfo featureInfo
```

you should have: `jaxws-2.2 [1.0.0]` in the list.

Once you install the feature, if you are using Eclipse, you will need to refresh the available features. Do following:

- Go to `Window > Preferences > Server Runtime Environments`
- Select Liberty runtime and click `Edit`
- Click `Advanced options...` link
- And click `Refresh`.

Then `jax-ws` feature should be visible while configuring `server.xml`.